# Windows IP to IP proxy

Tags: windows, networking, python, proxy, ip

I'm trying to make a proxy (in python) that would capture request from an app, print them and then send the request to the original destination. I've got the python part ready, but I ran into an issue.

The app I want to proxy connects directly via IP address (so hosts file doesn't help me for redirecting it to my proxy), I found I solution using `netsh int ip add addr 1 IP/32 st=ac sk=tr`. The problem is, this will also redirect traffic from my python proxy, thus making it impossible to deliver the request to the original destination.

What I need is a solution that would allow me to only redirect traffic from a single app or somehow bypass the `netsh` rule in the proxy. What can I do to achieve that?

**Edit:** One solution which came to my mind is using another device to host the proxy, that way it would still have the correct route to the original destination, but this is not ideal.

Comment: Did you try to use one of the well known proxy solutions which kind of exist for this purpose? Why could you not set the connection point to localhost and let your proxy rewrite it to the destination?

Comment: @Seth could you maybe point me towards one of them? From my googling I couldn't really find something that would suit my purpose, as I would like to inspect the packets (and possibly send some custom ones), but maybe I was just searching the wrong term.

Comment: If you want to inspect the package why not use e.g. Wireshark? Fiddler would probably one of the common solutions.

Comment: I did to get generic sense of what te app is sending, but as I said, I also want to implement a way to send custom requestes.